# randomForest classifier create issue with test data in R

Tags: r, csv, random-forest

I have two csv file, one for train and one for test. I can create a classifier model using train.csv file with no issue. And the classifier works correctly.

```r
library(caret)  # For data preprocessing and model training
library(randomForest)  # For building the classifier model
library(zoo)

data <- read.csv("train.csv")
predictors <- data[, -ncol(data)]
response <- data[, ncol(data)]
set.seed(123)  # For reproducibility
train_indices <- createDataPartition(response, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train_data <- predictors[train_indices, ]
train_labels <- response[train_indices]
test_data <- predictors[-train_indices, ]
test_labels <- response[-train_indices]
classifier_model <- randomForest(train_data, train_labels)
predictions <- predict(classifier_model, test_data)
confusion_matrix <- confusionMatrix(predictions, test_labels)
print(confusion_matrix)
```

But when I load my test.csv data and apply the classifier it give me error:

```r
test_ <- read.csv("test.csv")
test_predictors <- test_[, -ncol(test_)]
test_labels <- test_[,ncol(test_)]
```

#### Error

```
Error in predict.randomForest(classifier_model, test_predictors) :
Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.
```

I also compare the `colnames` and class for each column.

```r
# Compare column names
identical(colnames(predictors), colnames(test_predictors))
train_column_names <- colnames(predictors)
test_column_names <- colnames(test_predictors)

for (col_name in train_column_names) {
  # Get the class of the column in train_predictors
  train_col_class <- class(predictors[[col_name]])
  
  # Get the class of the column in test_predictors
  test_col_class <- class(test_predictors[[col_name]])
  
  # Compare the classes
  if (train_col_class != test_col_class) {
    cat("Data type mismatch in column:", col_name, "\n")
    cat("Train column class:", train_col_class, "\n")
    cat("Test column class:", test_col_class, "\n\n")
  }
}
```

Give me `TRUE`. I couldn't find any issues but the classifier give the above error. Is there any way to trace where the actual problem happening?